# Login and token auth in CakePHP 2.7.5

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, token

I have a login function in CakePHP 2.7 that seems like it should be split up into two parts.  One conditional to handle a first time login with token authentication and then another conditional to handle cases when the user is already logged in.  I tried putting the following block in an `else` statement below the very first `if` conditional but that threw all sorts of errors.

```
  if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    if ($this->Auth->login()) {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
  }
```

Would there be any relatively easy way to separate this function into an `if` and an `else` or `elseif`  statement to handle both of those cases with the token authentication?

`Login()` and `beforeFilter()` from user controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('check_login', 'index', 'wsdl', 'admin_wsdl', 'admin_service');
    parent::beforeFilter();
  }

function login() { 
    echo 'login function';
    print_r($this->data);
    if (!empty($this->data) && $this->Auth->user()) {
      echo 'if statement true';
      // Delete all old tokens
      $this->Tour->recursive = -1;
      $this->Tour->deleteAll(array('Tour.userid' => $this->Auth->user('userid')));
      // Create a new token
      $this->Tour->create();
      $this->Tour->save(array('token' => md5(rand()), 'userid' => $this->Auth->user('userid')));
      // Update login count
      $user = $this->User->read(null, $this->Auth->user('userid'));
      $user['User']['logincount']++;
      $this->User->saveField('logincount', $user['User']['logincount']);
      // Update last login time
      $this->User->saveField('lastlogin', date('Y-m-d h:m:s'));
       if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
      }

    }
  }
```

`beforeFilter()` in the app controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->setLayout();

    if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User.userid')) {
      $tour = $this->Tour->findByUserid($this->Session->read('Auth.User.userid'));
      $user = $this->Auth->user();
      $tour = $this->Tour->findByUserid($user['User']['userid']);
      $user['Tour'] = $tour['Tour'];
      $this->set('user', $user);
    }else if (isset($_GET['token'])) {
      $tour = $this->Tour->read(null, $_GET['token']);
      if ($tour) {
        $tour['Tour']['sessionmodified'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->Tour->save($tour);
        $this->set('user', $tour);
      }
    }
  }
```